# Error Running React Native APP on Physical device

Tags: react-native

I followed every step on getting started page of react native for Linux machine. I installed everything but can't run hello world app on my phone.
When I run the react-native run-android command I get the following error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
15 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 14 up-to-date
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

I also ran react-native info

```
 React Native Environment Info:
System:
  OS: Linux 4.15 elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki
  CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7200U CPU @ 2.50GHz
  Memory: 134.00 MB / 7.67 GB
  Shell: 4.3.48 - /bin/bash
Binaries:
  Node: 10.11.0 - /usr/bin/node
  npm: 6.4.1 - /usr/bin/npm
  Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
  Android SDK:
    Build Tools: 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.3
    API Levels: 26, 27, 28
npmPackages:
  react: 16.5.0 => 16.5.0 
  react-native: 0.57.1 => 0.57.1 
npmGlobalPackages:
  react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

How do I run hello world app on my physical device.Help me with this.

Comment: Have you enabled debugging on your android phone?  Also what shows if your run 'adb devices' in command line.  Do you see your device?

Comment: I resolved this by uninstalling openjdk8 and installing oracle8 jdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by uninstalling openjdk and installing oracle8 jdk